# LaTeX compilation bug when using todonotes in abstract of elsarticle class document

Tags: compiling, abstract, elsarticle, todonotes

I'm preparing a review using the `elsarticle` class in LaTeX. There's various threads to keep track of, so I'm using `todonotes` to note issues so I can keep writing. I've found that using `\todo` in the abstract environment causes the compilation to pause with the message

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost
Hitting return to proceed gives 
! LaTeX Error: This may be a LaTeX bug.
and the only help offered is 
"Call for help" ... HELP!
```

In a multi-page document I found that the bug upsets the text around other todonotes at the end of a sentence by not inserting space between it and the next sentence.

I could neglect the `elsarticle` class in favour of preparing the text using `article` but it would still be nice to get to the bottom of this issue. I don't know where to start with this matter given the not-so-optimistic LaTeX error. Suggestions are welcome. 
I thought I'd report this in case this `\todo` issue affects other document classes.

A minimal working example follows:

```
 \documentclass[review,numbers,authoryear,sort]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage[textwidth=2.3cm, textsize=scriptsize,color=green!40]{todonotes}
 \setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5cm}  

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{To catch a bug \ldots }

 \author[mymainaddress]{me}
\ead{my email}
 \address[mymainaddress]{my address}

\begin{abstract}
I'm having a problem with an Elsevier style file.\todo{Get to the point!} 
Maybe someone at Stackexchange can suggest how to get the todo note to appear?
  \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction} \label{s:intro}
Words to go here \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `abstract` environment immediately typesets the text and stores it in a box register; no float can thus appear in it.

Answer (score 2):

The `abstract` environment immediately typesets the text and saves it in a box, so there can be no float like `\todo`.

You *can* do as follows for your drafts, getting a result which is alike the standard. But remember to remove all the additional code together with the “to do notes” when you submit the document.

```
\documentclass[review,numbers,authoryear,sort]{elsarticle}

%%% Do this only for your drafts
\usepackage[textwidth=2.3cm, textsize=scriptsize,color=green!40]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xpatch,environ,ragged2e}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}

\RenewEnviron{abstract}{%
  \xdef\theabstracttext{%
    \unexpanded{%
      \def\baselinestretch{1}\noindent\unskip\textbf{Abstract}\par\medskip
      \noindent\unskip\ignorespaces}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
  }%
}
\def\theabstracttext{}
\xpatchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
  {\ifvoid\absbox}
  {\ifx\theabstracttext\empty\else\printtheabstracttext\fi\ifvoid\absbox}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\printtheabstracttext}{{%
  \begin{trivlist}
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \item\relax
  \theabstracttext
  \end{trivlist}
}}
%%% end addition

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{To catch a bug \ldots }

\author[mymainaddress]{me}
\ead{my email}
\address[mymainaddress]{my address}

\begin{abstract}
I'm having a problem with an Elsevier style file.\todo{Get to the point!} 
Maybe someone at Stackexchange can suggest how to get the todo note to appear?
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction} \label{s:intro}
Words to go here \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! I like that I can continue to use `todonotes` and that those aside, the document retains the formatting intended. This is likely to be even more useful when I get back to working with a collaborator and we have differing opinions.

Comment: @JasonWhyte Just don't use the `elsarticle` class for the drafts.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want the  notes in the final version (rather odd if you are using the `elsarticle` class) what I would do is just add  the `inline` option to the `\todo` command and the `obeyFinal` option to the `todonotes` package. MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{elsarticle} % add "final" option to hide todo notes
\usepackage[obeyFinal]{todonotes} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
Some \todo[inline]{Get to the point!} text
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Of course, while a margin note not touch the text layout, this MWE break the paragraph and increase the height of the abstract, but hide the note and  see the final layout in the above MWE is as easy as just add "`final`" to the document class options. I think that is good balance between results and simplicity, mostly considering that if you should submit your code, anyway you will ending clearing manually any related code with the notes.

Answer (score 1):

Just as another solution.

I tend to use `fixme` for this particular reason: that todo cannot be used everywhere.

I use this setup:

```
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{
  layout=marginnote,
  marginface=\normalfont\tiny,
  envface=,
  inlineface=,
  innerlayout=noinline,
}
```

And `\fxnote{text}` in the text

It comes with the cost that two `\fxnote` in the same line with be typeset on top of each other. That is generally ok, and `\listoffixmes` can be used to list all notes.

Here is an adjustment of the OPs MWE:

```
\documentclass[review,numbers,authoryear,sort]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage[textwidth=2.3cm, textsize=scriptsize,color=green!40]{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5cm}  

\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{
  layout=marginnote,
  marginface=\normalfont\tiny,
  envface=,
  inlineface=,
  innerlayout=noinline,
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{To catch a bug \ldots }

 \author[mymainaddress]{me}
\ead{my email}
 \address[mymainaddress]{my address}

\begin{abstract}
I'm having a problem with an Elsevier style file.\fxnote{Get to the point!} 
Maybe someone at Stackexchange can suggest how to get the todo note to appear?
  \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction} \label{s:intro}
Words to go here \ldots
\end{document}
```